# Android:FourSquare Setting->Sharing with other networks

Tags: android, foursquare

I am done with this foursquare integration. If i want to add setting which means in foursquare site “Settings->Sharing with other networks” through my **mobile application**.How can i do that?

I have seen its developer website's API [here](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/). There is one Endpoint "settings". But i don't understand that how can i set Connect/Disconnect from Facebook,Twitter A/C through android application. So when I Connect & Add Facebook A/c through my application its updates automatically on website which is shown in 2nd Screen Shot. [image]

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You unfortunately can't let a Foursquare user connect to Facebook through your application. Connecting Foursquare to Facebook requires Foursquare itself to save some information from Facebook and we don't let other apps do this.

For a user that has already connected Facebook, you can, however, [change what gets posted to Facebook](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/settings/set) and [add a check-in to Facebook](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/checkins/add) through the `broadcast` parameter.